# Javascript write int value in a text file

Tags: javascript, slider, fwrite

Working on an HTML project, I would like to use sliders to change some int values, and write them to a text file.
The server is Lighttpd under Linux Debian.

Actually, I did this for the slider:

```
<input type="range" name="lightInputName" id="lightInputId" value="1" min="1" max="20" onchange="getvalor(this.value);" oninput="lightOutputId.value = lightInputId.value">
<input size="1" type="text" name="lightOutputName" id="lightOutputId"></input>
```

My question is:

- How can I write the int value "lightOutputName" to a text file ?

Thank you so much for your help and support.

Best regards,

Comment: What have you tried? Also, js in the browser can't write to a text file, so this is probably not the tag you want to use. You'll need to have server-side code running for that.

Comment: Hi Cruiser, What do you mean by server side code ? PHP for example ? If yes, could you please give me an example which works for Lighttpd on Linux ? Thanks

Comment: Yes, something like php, or node.js, or java. But no, I cannot give you an example as you haven't given us any details about your application. I'm not going to just write an entire backend for you. You need to try some things and ask for help when you're stuck